# Python Discord Get multuple messages after command

Tags: python, discord.py

What I'm trying to do is create a bot that will start off when an admin types !start. After that, users can type in a message that can only be 3 characters in length. EAch of these messages will be displayed in an embedded message. When an admin hits !stop then the messages will stopped being recorded. Right now, I can !start and !stop, but I can't get the messages in between. The msg2 variable doesn't even get printed out.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('!start'):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Starting")

    def check(msg):
         return len(msg.content) == 3

    while (not await client.wait_for_message(author=message.author, content='!stop')):
        msg2 = await client.wait_for_message(check=check)
        print (msg2.content)

    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Stopping")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get all the messages, including the stop message, from the same `wait_for_message`.  Otherwise you start waiting for the `stop` message and never start waiting for the 3 letter messages.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):    
    if message.content.startswith('!start'):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Starting")

        def check(msg):
             return len(msg.content) == 3 or msg.content.startswith('!stop')

        msgs = []
        while True:
            msg2 = await client.wait_for_message(check=check)
            if msg2.content.startswith('!stop'): 
                break
            msgs.append(msg2.content)

        await client.send_message(message.channel, "\n".join(msgs))
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Stopping")
```